# Accessing javascript libraries from Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, vis.js

I am writing a small nodejs application to pick up content from couchdb and plan to visualize it using [vis.js](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline.html)
In the process, I learnt about express, jade and have utilized them.
However now I realize that vis.js must be called from the jade template. So I added the following to my jade file

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
head
title= title
link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/bootstrap.css", type="text/css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/main.css", type="text/css")
body(style="background-image:url(/images/background.jpg)")

div(class="container", id="visualization")
script.
var options = {};
var data = new vis.DataSet(options);
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);
```

Does it make sense to do this? I have got errors related to indentation and spaces (as typical to jade).
Thanks!

Comment: That's because jade actually *requires* you to indent.

Comment: yes I understand. There are 2 spaces before line 10 and one tab space each for line 11,12,13,14

Comment: @user1384205 Jade expects indentations to be consistent per file. You'll have to choose spaces (and how many) or tabs, then use that choice throughout the view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue is your indentation. This should be correct:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/bootstrap.css", type="text/css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/main.css", type="text/css")
    body(style="background-image:url(/images/background.jpg)")

        div(class="container", id="visualization")
        script.
            var options = {};
            var data = new vis.DataSet(options);
            var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
            new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);
```

You can also simplify `div(class="container", id="visualization")` to `#visualization.container`

Comment: There were 2 spaces before line 10 and one tab space each for line 11,12,13,14. I also tried 1 tab space on line 10 (script.) and 2 tab spaces for every line below that (line 11,12,13,14). Here is the error           8| 
       9|     div(class="container", id="visualization") 
     > 10| script. 
     11| var options = {}; 
     12| var data = new vis.DataSet(options); 13| var container = document.getElementById('visualization'); 

Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Answer (score 0):

make sure to load vis's css and js file in your template and then you can get the data from the database through node and send it to the view and use it .

```
app.get('/therout', function(req, res) {
    var dbdata;
    // get the data from the database 
    res.render('viewname', { dbdata: dbdata})
}
```

in the template

```
data = new vis.DataSet(dbdata);
```

Comment: yes. I have done exactly that.  response.render('timeline.jade', data) seems to work too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jade expects either all elements be aligned by space or by tab but not both. Once I changed all the lines to be aligned by space, it worked. Thanks everyone.